# How to combine raster data into CSV attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table, csv

Recently I am working on some raster data transfer in to .csv. I am doing this manually. First I upload my coordinate points in to raster then I click the information button then I click on every coordinate points and write manually. See the images.

[image]

[image]

Is there any alternative way in QGIS?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `add raster values to points` tool, which is available in the toolbox?

Answer (score 4):

Use the geoprocessing tool
[Sample raster values](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/sampling_raster_data.html):

> This algorithm creates a new vector layer with the same attributes of
> the input layer and the raster values corresponding on the point
> location. If the raster layer has more than one band, all the band
> values are sampled

Answer (score 3):

To create a new attribute in the point layer with the correspoding value of the raster at this point, create a new field with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and this expression:

```
raster_value("raster",1, $geometry)
```

- `raster` is the name of your raster layer
- `1` is the number of the band you want to get.

**Be sure to have both layers in the same CRS.**